# rails tire elasticsearch weird error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have indexed a `Car` model with one car record `mercedes benz` in the database. If I search for the word `benz` I get an error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in CarsController#index

Couldn't find all Cars with IDs (1, 3) (found 1 results, but was looking for 2)
```

If I search for `hello` I get:

```
Couldn't find Car with id=2
```

Other random search terms work returning accurate results.

So it's basically random errors generated by random search terms. What could be the cause of this?

Controller:

```
def index
 if params[:query].present?
    @cars = Car.search(params)
 else
    @cars = Car.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)
 end    
end
```

Model:

```
  def self.search(params)
   tire.search(load: true, page: params[:page], per_page: 10) do |s|
    s.query { string params[:query]} if params[:query].present?
   end
  end
```

Comment: I think your index is not in sync with your DB. You have deleted some car records from your DB, but they are not deleted from the search index. Recreate the index and try the search.

Comment: I can't find a tire reindex command. Can I run rake db:drop + rake db:setup to reindex?

Comment: You can delete the index (eg: curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/cars/') and then re-index (rake setup:tire).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because, you are using the load => true option to load the search results from database. The activerecord seems to be missing in DB, but the elasticsearch index contains the same document.

Reindex is not always the solution IMHO.

The best solution is to delete the document when it is deleted in db. You can use the after_destroy callback for this.

Tire remove api is used to remove a single document from index.

```
Tire.index('my-index-name').remove('my-document-type', 'my-document-id')
```

Reference: https://github.com/karmi/tire/issues/43

Comment: Can you please explain how/where to use the after_destroy callback?

Comment: Just use this in your model, http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods/after_commit. `after_commit :some_method, :on => :destroy`. Inside some_method implement the code to delete the document from elasticsearch. The one I have given in the answer.