# Tire Elasticsearch could not find all Users with IDs

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, elasticsearch, tire

I'm using Tire and ElasticSearch to retrieve a bunch of users using `load: true`, and I'm seeing odd parameters for the IDs. The error I'm receiving is:

```
Couldn't find all Users with IDs (mhNpuOspSQeUWpHExeVEPA, iSum7MecRw2FKbbFD8NSYg, vl3VMWESQiuECI56fBY-TQ, y0Wy3aOtQR26zQle8_K9Sw, 56625, 479165, 479169, 62911, 479181, 479173) (found 6 results, but was looking for 10)
```

I'm sure that the 6 results that are found are the integer IDs, but what are the four alphanumeric IDs, and how should I best deal with them? Hopefully this is something obvious, but I've not found anything just yet that explains this.

**EDIT**

Example content of to_indexed_json:

```
{"email"=>"lucy@example.com", "forename"=>"Lucy", "id"=>5070, "surname"=>"Test", "username"=>"", "is_deleted"=>false}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of another SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15026612/rails-tire-elasticsearch-weird-error/16117621#16117621 Anyways added the answer.

Comment: Can you please post your mapping and the to_indexed_json code, if possible, to analyse the alphanumeric IDs?

Comment: You can also have a look at this patch too. This is tested and works fine (I'm using it currently). https://github.com/jeyb/tire/commit/17b6eca0e086eb0cce6251404caf4755d4c6a755

Comment: Thanks for taking a look Vamsi - I saw the other question, but it does not address the alphanumeric IDS. Moving to using where instead of find is all good and well, but I'd rather understand the origin of these odd IDs.

Comment: Is it possible that something weird is happening while indexing itself? Is it possible to post to_indexed_json and mapping?

Comment: There is nothing odd in the to_indexed_json - obviously I can't generate it for the users with the odd ids as they don't exist (ID is just an integer). I've updated my question with the contents of it.

Comment: Not sure what actually is happening here. Out of ideas. Just a wild guess. Do the 4 alphanumeric IDs by any chance match with the elasticsearch node hashes. You can verify it using the command `curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_nodes?process=true&pretty=true'`

Answer (score 0):

This happens because, you are using the load => true option to load the search results from database. The activerecord seems to be missing in DB, but the elasticsearch index contains the same document.

You can try reindexing the data. Reindex is not always the solution IMHO.

The best solution is to delete the document when it is deleted in db. You can use the after_destroy callback for this.

Tire remove api is used to remove a single document from index.

```
Tire.index('my-index-name').remove('my-document-type', 'my-document-id')
```

Reference: https://github.com/karmi/tire/issues/43

Comment: Yeah, I get all of that, and callbacks *should* be taking care of the deletion of documents. My question was: What are those alphanumeric ID's and where do they come from?

Comment: Sorry I overlooked the question of alphanumeric ID's.